# How to check whether a byte array corrupted FastInfoSet Document

Tags: java, fastinfoset

How to check whether a byte array is a corrupted FastInfoSet Document or just binary garbage?

I mean maybe exists some binary "header" that we can check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is exists static method [isFastInfosetDocument](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/xml/internal/fastinfoset/Decoder.java.html) in `com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.Decoder` class that check the first 4 bytes in `java.io.InputStream`.

Of course it will work only if not corrupted the first 4 bytes.